# How to decode JSON stringify from React in a different php file

Tags: php, json, reactjs, react-redux

in React I have used redux and passing data like below:

```
const requestOptions = {
method: 'POST',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
body: JSON.stringify(user)
};
return fetch('http://localhost:8080/react-crud/api/signup.php', requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  return response.text().then(text => {
    const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
    if (!response.ok) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
      //  logout();
       //alert("done");
       console.log("done");
      }
      const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    return data;
  });
}
```

and in PHP i am calling below code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

 $tempData = html_entity_decode($_POST['text']);
$obj = json_decode($tempData);
 //$obj = json_decode($_POST['user'],false);
 echo($_POST["user"]);
 print_r($obj);
```

But nothing is printing its showing error"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()"

can any one please help me out to resolve this.

Comment: I think you should encode not decode on the PHP side

Comment: I tried encoding but its still not working,any idea

Answer (score 0):

use in PHP decode function,like below.Now its working fine:

```
 $formdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$name = $formdata["name"];
$email = $formdata["email"];
$password = $formdata["password"];
```